# 404 when requiring wordpress file from Yii with spl_autoload

Tags: php, wordpress, yii, spl-autoload-register

I am using Yii 1.1 in a project where I need to fetch the top blog titles from a wordpress site. I am using the following code for this. On using this however, I am getting 404 for all pages when this layout is being used. I am not able to understand how this is affecting the final status code. Commenting out this specific block removes all error.

I was actually okay with the 404 till it start messing with some vital javscript files.

```
    spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
    require_once('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');
    spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'post_status'=>'publish'
        ));
    foreach($recent_posts as $post) {
        echo '<li><a href="', get_permalink($post['ID']), '">', $post['post_title'], '</a></li>';
    }
```

The file `./blog/wp-blog-header.php` exists and I am able to list down the blog articles using the above code. It is just the status code that is causing trouble.

Comment: Do you have the file (wp-blog-header.php) on your machine or you are trying it from another site ? Confused by your sentence: "where I need to fetch the top blog titles from a wordpress site"

Comment: Yes, I shall add this info. I just need to display the list of latest blog articles on the yii layout file.

Comment: Please explain, if the link in the foreach pointing to a 404 page? If so, then you need to inspect what get_permalink() is returning and include this in the post.